# How to make the DOM element stay(after refresh), which was added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Making a simple todo list, here I add task dynamically, but when I   refresh page the dynamically added DOM will go off, I want that to stay. Is it possible?

**Html**

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text here" id="todoTxt" type="text" name="todo">
  <button id="todoSub" class="btn btn-success form-control">Submit</button>
    <div id="todoList" class="list-group">
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item done">task one<span class="badge">x</span></button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item">task two<span class="badge">x</span></button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item">task three<span class="badge">x</span></button>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function addlist(content){
        var newListItem = $('<button></button>');
        $(newListItem).addClass('list-group-      item').text(content).append('<span class="badge">x</span>');
        $('#todoList').append(newListItem);
    }
        $('#todoSub').click(function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var content = $('#todoTxt').val();
        addlist(content);
    });
        //And Here I am unable to remove dynamically added DOM
        $('#todoList button span').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit prasad, Could you please educate me on right formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you have to save the newly created html some where on persistent storage like `file`, `database`, `local storage`, `session`.

Means, every time a new html for a task is generated dynamically, you have to store it in any one from the above listed storage. And when the page renders after refreshing or first time you have to check that storage and render the recent created html to. And when user remove that html, then remov it from that storage to.

Answer (score 0):

yes. its possible  but not whit html and **jquery** or **js**.
you need to use a **database** to save elements added whit DOM.